# Matcher of Regex expression is false while the expression, pattern and string are all valid

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am using a regex regular expression like so:

```
@Test
fun timePatternFromInstantIsValid() {
    val instantOfSometimeEarlier = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofMinutes((1..3).random().toLong()))
    val timeOfEvent = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(instantOfSometimeEarlier)
    val regex = "(\\d{2}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01]))T(?:(?:([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\\d):)?([0-5]?\\d)"
    val acceptedDatePattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
    val matcher: Matcher = microsoftAcceptedDatePattern.matcher(timeOfEvent)
    val isMatchToAcceptedDatePattern: Boolean = matcher.matches() 

    print(isMatchToAcceptedDatePattern)
}
```

isMatchToAcceptedDatePattern for some reason is returning false which probably indicates something is wrong in my regex BUT, when checking it on multiple regex websites I'm getting a valid match. any ideas why?

try it yourself:
https://www.regextester.com/ or here:
https://regex101.com/

*my regex - raw (as in the websites):*

(\d{2}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))T(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)

*pattern example returned like this (it gets returned without the " ' " near the "T"):*

2021-04-01T11:12:51 (when I debug this is what I get)

*date pattern:*

yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

could someone inlight me please?

Answer (score 0):

You use `matcher.matches()` which is like pre- and appending `^` resp. `$` to your regex. [Such a regex won't work](https://regex101.com/r/6QHsjF/1).

Instead you should either:

- use `matcher.find()` which returns `true` if a match could be found.
- prepend `\d{2}` to your regex and still use `matcher.matches()`: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uaUbBw/1)